# How to keep content within the view?

Tags: html, css

I currently have a container and a content inside.

How can I keep the content within the browser?

Here is the code:

```
      <h1>
        Content inside
      </h1>
```

Comment: *"Thank you and will be accepting answer and voting up"* has no place in your question.

Comment: Rolled-back your question *edit* since code is necessary for a proper Question formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by simply adding to `body`

```
overflow: hidden;
```

and making sure to use

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

or removing `width:100%;`

*box-sizing:border-box;* fixes the issue of having a 100% width padded - placing the paddings within the box model of your element.

```css
*{margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
html,body{height:100%;font:14px/1.4 sans-serif;}

body{overflow:hidden;}

#container {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 30px; 
}
```

```html
  <div id="container">
      <h1>
        Content inside
      </h1>
      <div>
        I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. I currently have a container and a content inside. When the browser gets minimized, the content inside overflows, and the scroll bars appear. 
      </div>
  </div>
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/botehun/1/edit?html,css,output)***

Comment: @RokoCBuljan But the content still stays outside the browser and only makes the scrollbars disappear, rather than keeping the whole content inside the browser.

Comment: @RokoCBuljan overflow:hidden; is simply hiding the scroll bars, correct?

Comment: @LyManeug yep. You can try yourself.

Comment: @RokoCBuljan THank you

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```
#container {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.clear_ {
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
}


<div id="container">
      <h1>
        Content inside
      </h1>
      <div>
      your text here
      </div>
<div class="clear_"></div>
  </div>
```

I hope this help